# Jest/React-testing-library: .find is not a function in the tested component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, formik

I have been doing integration tests of my project's front-end pages with jest and react-testing-library, and have come accross an error I don't fully understand.

The page I am testing renders a formik form that the users inputs data for an commercial institution:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  FormGroup, Label, Row,
} from 'reactstrap';
import {
  Field, getIn, FieldArray, useFormikContext,
} from 'formik';

import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';
import Select from 'react-select';
import {
  institutionTypeAtom,
} from 'recoil/institution';
import { Colxx } from 'components/common/CustomBootstrap';
import IntlMessages from 'helpers/IntlMessages';

import { FormikStep } from 'components/Stepper/Step';

const InstitutionStep1 = ({ label, isView, validationSchema }) => {
  const {
    values, errors, touched, setFieldValue,
  } = useFormikContext();
  const types = useRecoilValue(institutionTypeAtom);

  const typeFind = (values) => {
    types.find((t) => t.institution_type_id === values.institution_type_id);
    return values.institution_type_id;
  };

  return (
    <FormikStep>
        <Colxx xxs="4">
          <FormGroup>
            <Label>
              <IntlMessages id="institution.type" />
            </Label>
            <Select
              placeholder="Selecione o tipo"
              value={types.find((t) => t.institution_type_id === values.institution_type_id)}
              isDisabled={isView}
              onChange={(selectedType) => {
                setFieldValue('institution_type_id', selectedType.institution_type_id);
              }}
              options={types}
              className="react-select"
              classNamePrefix="react-select"
              name="institution_type_id"
              aria-label="institution_type_id"
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.institution_type}
              getOptionValue={(option) => option.institution_type_id}
            />
            {getIn(errors, 'institution_type_id') && getIn(touched, 'institution_type_id') && (
            <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
              {getIn(errors, 'institution_type_id')}
            </div>
            )}
          </FormGroup>
        </Colxx>
      </Row>
    </FormikStep>
  );
};

export default InstitutionStep1;
```

and one of the input fields is a select where he can select a type for the institution (private, public, foreign...). I am also using a stepper, and formikStep is the final component from that stepper that receives the initialValues:

```
export const institutionInitialValues: InitialValues<BaseInstitutionType> = (institution = {}) => ({
  institution_type_id: institution.institution_type_id ? institution.institution_type_id : '',
  deleted: !!institution.deleted,
});
```

And I have written my test to get the users select from the rendered page, but I am also very new to the testing area so I am referencing other tests that were on this project already:

```
import React from 'react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import {
  cleanup, screen, act, render, waitFor, renderWithRecoilSnapshot,
} from 'testWrapper';
import * as institution from 'services/adminModules/institution';
import {
  generateMockInstitution, mockAxiosResponse,
} from 'helpers/testMocks';
import { institutionTypeAtom } from 'recoil/institution';
import InstitutionForm from '../../views/app/admin/InstitutionsPage/InstitutionForm';

let createInstitution: jest.SpyInstance;

const mockInstitution = generateMockInstitution();

const mockSubmit = jest.fn();

const mockClose = jest.fn();

const renderComponent = () => renderWithRecoilSnapshot(<InstitutionForm
  handleClose={mockClose}
  handleSubmit={mockSubmit}
/>,
({ set }) => {
  set(institutionTypeAtom, 1);
});

describe('InstitutionFormPage', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  beforeEach(() => {
    createInstitution = jest.spyOn(institution, 'createInstitution').mockImplementation(async () => mockAxiosResponse());
    jest.spyOn(institution, 'getInstitution').mockImplementation(async () => mockAxiosResponse());
  });

  it('should submit institution data', async () => {
    renderComponent();

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByText('loading')).not.toBeInTheDocument());

    screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();

   
    const institution_type_id = screen.getByRole('select', { name: 'institution_type_id' });

    expect(institution_type_id).toBeInTheDocument();

    await act(async () => {
      await userEvent.selectOptions(institution_type_id, mockInstitution.institution_type_id);
    });

    const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /salvar/i });
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();

    await act(async () => {
      await userEvent.click(button);
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockInstitution));
  });
});
```

Seemingly, the test is correct, but I am getting an error from when I run it's test that says that a .find I am using, in the component, is not a function.

[image]

So my main question would be, does this mean the test is correct and is appropriately catching a code error? Or is it wrong and it's not able to proceed? Also, the code it complains about works fine, and I was taught that an integration test tests api requests, so is there a reason why the test would complain about it, but the code would work fine?

Comment: Can you do console.log(types) inside your component and re-run the test again . Looks like types is not an `Array`

Comment: You're right. The console log shows that types is an Array when I am running the project and accessing the component and using it, but when I run the test, the console log only prints the number 1. I guess this means the mock of the select is wrong then